# Want to get value of the Textfield in React-js which has dynamic drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textfield

I am using an Autocomplete field in my react-js project. The code for the field is given below.

```
<Autocomplete
    id="Autocomplete"
    placeholder="I want ..."
    className="md-cell md-cell--4"
    data={services}
    filter={Autocomplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
    inputStyle={style.inputstyle}
    style={style.rootstyle}
    listStyle={style.liststyle}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this.value)}
/>
```

It is an autocomplete field something like this
[image]

Now what I want is to get the value once the user select his choice. By using the onChange, I am only getting the value entered by the user or I get the complete value after the user either presses space after selecting the choice.

What I want is to get the value from the field as soon as user selects his choice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wat autocomplete library are you using ?

Comment: @Panther, I am using React-md's Autocompletes library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in doc, you should make use of `onAutocomplete` to get the autocompleted value. I think you are assuming `onChange` would do that for you. Instead replace `onChange` with `onAutocomplete`.

```
<Autocomplete
id="Autocomplete"
placeholder="I want ..."
className="md-cell md-cell--4"
data={services}
filter={Autocomplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
inputStyle={style.inputstyle}
style={style.rootstyle}
listStyle={style.liststyle}
onAutocomplete={this.handleChange.bind(this.value)}
/>
```

Doc here: https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/autocompletes?tab=1#autocomplete-proptypes-on-autocomplete